# How to prevent TensorFlow ANN from converging to a single output

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow

I've created an ANN with 25 inputs, 3 output classes, and two hidden layers. Every time I train the model on my complete dataset, it converges to a configuration that always outputs the most common result tensor: [0, 0, 1]. When I *filter* the training data so that *all three outputs* are equally represented, the ANN will still converge to a model that has 33% accuracy, and clings to one output.

My dataset has proven correlation, so that isn't the issue. The data is shuffled before the session, so order bias is definitely not a factor. I've tried using tf.reduce_mean and tf.reduce_max as cost functions, and AdamOptimizer and RMSPropOptimizer as optimizers, but to no avail. The issue persists when I play with the learning rate, batch size, and layer sizes. Is there a cost function or optimizer that will solve my problem, or perhaps a way of handling my data differently?

Comment: Does the model work for 2 classes? That would be easier to debug.

Comment: Interestingly, using 2 classes causes the same problem...

Comment: Are you normalizing your input data?